# alarmManager.setRepeating always shows Notification immediately regardless of time

Tags: android

I am writing an application that requires user input at a set time everyday. In my preference fragment I use alarmManager.setRepeating to set the time at which a notification should be displayed. When the notification is opened it takes the user to where they can enter the input the app needs.

What happens however is the as soon as the notification time is set the notification fires. I know that in the documentation it says that if the time used in alarmManager.setRepeating is already past the notification will fire immediatly. I have tried setting the notification time hours in the future, and I have tried hardcoding the notification time to hours in the future. It always fires immediatly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**My Preference Fragment**

```
package test.test;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static android.content.Context.ALARM_SERVICE;

public class Preferences extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("Preferences", "onCreate: ");

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("Preferences", "onResume: ");
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d("Preferences", "onPause: ");
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
    {
        Log.d("Preferences", "onSharedPreferenceChanged: ");

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        if(key.equals("Mood_Notification_Time"))
        {
            if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Show_Mood_Notifications",true))
            {
                long time = sharedPreferences.getLong(key,64802000); // default value should be 20:00

                String temp = (new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS")).format(new Date(time));

                Log.d("Preferences", "onSharedPreferenceChanged: key value: " + sharedPreferences.getLong(key,64802000));
                Log.d("Preferences", temp);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),temp,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // show the time the notification is set for.

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NotificationReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(),123,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent); // cancel old notifications

                int t1  = Integer.parseInt((new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS")).format(new Date(time)).replace(":",""));
                int t2  = Integer.parseInt((new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS")).format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())).replace(":",""));

                // Determine if the time specified is past already or not. If it is past add 24 hour.
                if (t1 < t2)
                {
                    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1) + time, alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
                }
                else
                {
                    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
                }
            }
        }

        // Deactivate alarm if its been disabled in preference
        if(key.equals("Show_Mood_Notifications"))
        {
            if (!sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key,true))
            {
                Log.d("Preferences", "onSharedPreferenceChanged: Deactivate Notifications");

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NotificationReceiver.class);
                alarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(),123,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My Broadcast receiver**

```
package test.test;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat;

public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,EditMoodActivity.class);
        intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Drawable vectorDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.applogo, null);
        Bitmap myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable) vectorDrawable).getBitmap();

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).
                setSmallIcon(R.drawable.applogo).
                setLargeIcon(myLogo).
                setContentIntent(pendingIntent).
                setContentText("Set your mood for today.").
                setContentTitle("How was your day?").
                setSound(alarmSound).
                setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH).
                setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC).
                setVibrate(new long[]{100,50,100,50,100}).
                setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_ALARM).
                setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationManager.notify(100,builder.build());
    }
}
```

**TimePreference where I get the time that is used for triggerAtMillis parameter in alarmManager.setRepeating**

```
package test.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class TimePreference extends DialogPreference {
    private Calendar calendar;
    private TimePicker picker = null;

    public TimePreference(Context ctxt) {
        this(ctxt, null);
    }

    public TimePreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(ctxt, attrs, android.R.attr.dialogPreferenceStyle);
    }

    public TimePreference(Context ctxt, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(ctxt, attrs, defStyle);

        setPositiveButtonText("Set");
        setNegativeButtonText("Cancel");
        calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        picker = new TimePicker(getContext());
        picker.setIs24HourView(true);
        return (picker);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View v) {
        super.onBindDialogView(v);
        picker.setCurrentHour(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        picker.setCurrentMinute(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

        if (positiveResult) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, picker.getCurrentHour());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, picker.getCurrentMinute());

            setSummary(getSummary());
            if (callChangeListener(calendar.getTimeInMillis())) {
                persistLong(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
                notifyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
        return (a.getString(index));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue) {

        if (restoreValue) {
            if (defaultValue == null) {
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(getPersistedLong(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            } else {
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(getPersistedString((String) defaultValue)));
            }
        } else {
            if (defaultValue == null) {
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            } else {
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong((String) defaultValue));
            }
        }
        setSummary(getSummary());
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getSummary() {
        if (calendar == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return DateFormat.getTimeFormat(getContext()).format(new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
    }
}
```

Comment: `I have tried setting the notification time hours in the future` This is the correct approach, but there is no evidence that you did try to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The triggerAtMillis parameter of alarmManager.setRepeating is not simply time converted to Milliseconds. it is time in milliseconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

What was happening was that I was converting a time eg: 20:00 to milliseconds (64802000). When I used this as the value of triggerAtMillis it would add 64802000 to midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC which is 40 years in the past!

What I do now is to calculate the difference between the current time and the set time and use System.currentTimeMillis() + the result. Which adds the difference in milliseconds to the current timestamp, which results in a time in the future. So the notification now displays at the time I set and not immediately.

```
@Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
    {
        Log.d("Preferences", "onSharedPreferenceChanged: ");

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        if(key.equals("Mood_Notification_Time"))
        {
            if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Show_Mood_Notifications",true))
            {
                long time = sharedPreferences.getLong(key,64802000); // default value should be 20:00

                String temp = (new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS")).format(new Date(time));

                Log.d("Preferences", "onSharedPreferenceChanged: key value: " + sharedPreferences.getLong(key,64802000));
                Log.d("Preferences", temp);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),temp,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NotificationReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(),123,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent); // cancel old notifications

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

                String val1  = sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                String val2  = sdf.format(new Date(time));

                Date d1 = null;
                Date d2 = null;

                try {
                    d1 = sdf.parse(val1);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    d2 = sdf.parse(val2);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                long elapsed = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

                // Determine if the time specified is past already or not. If it is past add 24 hours so it displays the following day.
                if (elapsed < 0)
                {
                    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1) + elapsed, alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
                }
                else
                {
                    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + elapsed, alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
                }
            }
        }
```